# Adding column to cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a cell that has the following data:

```
Tom     Student
Jim     Faculty     
Clare   Student
```

What I want to do is add in another column in front to be a serial number.

```
1   Tom     Student
2   Jim     Faculty     
3   Clare   Student
```

Could someone give some advise please?

Comment: `[{1;2;3}, data]` where `data` is the cell array of strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have `A` defined as:

```
>> A={'Tom', 'Student'; 'Jim', 'Faculty'; 'Clare', 'Student'}

A = 

    'Tom'      'Student'
    'Jim'      'Faculty'
    'Clare'    'Student'
```

To add a column:

```
>> newCellCol = strsplit(num2str(1:size(A,1)))'

newCellCol = 

    '1'
    '2'
    '3'

>> A = [newCellCol A]

A = 

    '1'    'Tom'      'Student'
    '2'    'Jim'      'Faculty'
    '3'    'Clare'    'Student'

>>
```

For numeric arrays in the first column instead:

```
>> newCellCol = mat2cell(1:size(A,1),1,ones(1,size(A,1)))';
>> A = [newCellCol A]

A = 

    [1]    'Tom'      'Student'
    [2]    'Jim'      'Faculty'
    [3]    'Clare'    'Student'
```

You can also use `num2cell(1:size(A,1))'` in place of `mat2cell` above, as noted by Dan.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly how your cell array is organized, but if like below, you can do as follows:

```
A={{'Tom', 'Student'}, ...
    {'Jim', 'Faculty'}, ...
    {'Clare', 'Student'}};


sizeA = size(A,2);

for i = 1:sizeA
    A{i} = [i, A{i}]
end

% alternatively, instead of a for loop, you can use cellfun
% A = cellfun(@(x, i)[i x], A, num2cell(1:size(A, 2)), 'UniformOutput',0)

A{1}
A{2}
A{3}

ans = 

    [1]    'Tom'    'Student'


ans = 

    [2]    'Jim'    'Faculty'


ans = 

    [3]    'Clare'    'Student'
```

Comment: Why not just `a=num2cell(1:3)'; [a,A];`?

Comment: @Dan Better, but it gives an error "Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent."  I'm sure it could be fixed quickly, but I have to go now. No time to check. Thx.

Comment: I think that's because you have made A a cell array of cell arrays instead of a cell matrix like in the OP.