# Matlab Concatenation of Strings and Numbers

Tags: string, matlab, concatenation, dimensions

I have two 1-by-n matrices A and B. A is full of strings 'test' 'test2' 'test3; and so on and B has numbers 123, 4567, 89 and so on.

How do I interweave these two to get output like

```
test       123
test2     4567
test3       89
```

as a string?

My current issue is that strings have variable lengths and so [A; B] leads to problems with mismatched dimensions.

Comment: Are your `test`, `test2` stored as cells? And how about the numbers? You can't have strings and numbers in a regular array in MATLAB. cells are your best bet...

Comment: If the `test#` strings are of variable length, then how are you starring them in `A` currently? Either `A` is not a matrix and is a cell array or the strings are already padded with spaces (or some other black character). And what is `class(B)`? `char` or `double`?

Comment: You may need a cell array of cell arrays to deal with mismatched lengths, but in general, the approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674050/adding-column-to-cell-array/19674403#19674403) may be of help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB: Interweaving vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316304/matlab-interweaving-vectors)

Comment: @thewaywewalk: I disagree. It's not possible to use the same approach when strings are involved.

Comment: @RobertP the accepted answer is not working for this case, right, but the one below is similar to your answer. And we already had the same question last week ;)

Comment: @thewaywewalk: True, I didn't see it but yes, the second answer is similar. However, I felt it was necessary to point out that it had to be cells in this case (which is not the case for the other question).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to concatenate an array of strings (here `A` is a cell array, transformed into a char array `A2`) with a second array of strings (`B2`) corresponding to your numerical values `B`. The double to string conversion uses `sprintf`. The `%d` stands for integer format.

This code

```
A = {'test'; 'test2'; 'test3'}           %cell of strings      
B = [123; 4567; 89]                      %array of doubles 

A2 = char(A);                            %array of strings
B2 = reshape(sprintf('%8d',B), 8, [])';  %convert to integer + char + reshape + transpose
[A2 B2]
```

produces a char array where the number part are made of 8 char

```
ans =

test      123
test2    4567
test3      89
```